# SQL- How to combine two tables with two table counts with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Query in text: "Display all active users and the completed orders entered by them + the completed orders they are assigned to for the specified date range".

Here is the query i managed to create with only one count

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, COUNT(l.id) AS totalCompleted
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN orders l
        ON l.idDispatcher = u.id
        WHERE u.disabled = '0'
        AND l.smallStatus='1'
        AND l.dateAdded >= :from
        AND l.dateAdded <= :to
        GROUP BY u.firstname;
```

This gives me all the orders where the user is assigned to an order:

```
LEFT JOIN orders l
 ON l.idDispatcher = u.id
```

I need to combine this query with another one where the `COUNT(l.id)` is based on:

```
LEFT JOIN orders l
 ON l.addedById= u.id
```

When I try this:

```
LEFT JOIN orders l
 ON l.idDispatcher = u.id AND l.addedById= u.id
```

The `COUNT(l.id)` combines the result for assigned orders and orders added by the user, when i need it to be with two different numbers. I also tried putting a condition inside the COUNT, with no success

Comment: So... what's the problem/question exactly? What isn't working?

Comment: Hint: You can conditionally count like this: `sum(a = 123)`. That counts how often the condition is true.

Comment: @Rogue The problem is that i am able to get it to work in two separate queries and i'm trying to combine it into 1

Comment: So use two joins on the same table.

Comment: Can you provide an example, because i tried unsuccessfully. I'm not very experienced

Comment: @RaTre . . . Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @RaTre it's the same as joining two different tables, just `join` the same table twice with different names.

Comment: Guys, thank you for the replies. [Here](https://codeshare.io/OhCoT)'s a script of what i want to do, that's working. I'm trying to express the whole 'foreach' loop of the given script with SQL so it would look cleaner and more professional. Note that in the example 'orders' table is now 'newLoads'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly but if you said you got it working with two separate queries, and you need two counts, then just union the results together?

But if you need one count of ALL matches based on two separate conditions, use an "OR" in your join instead of "AND":

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, COUNT(l.id) AS totalCompleted
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN orders l
    ON l.idDispatcher = u.id
       or l.addedById= u.id
    WHERE u.disabled = '0'
    AND l.smallStatus='1'
    AND l.dateAdded >= :from
    AND l.dateAdded <= :to
    GROUP BY u.firstname, u.lastname;
```

Comment: [Check this out](https://codeshare.io/OhCoT). This is how i made it work. I'm just trying to combine all of that in one query